# Hats not appearing in top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

I can only guess this is a bug.
No matter which hat I wear in the profile page, it is not showing in the top menu. I just changed my profile picture, which is reflected correctly on first refresh of each open page.
Hats are showing correctly on the profile page & icon under a question/answer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Tested on Safari 14 & 15, Mojave & Monterey, also Chrome [& Firefox, from comments].

I just noticed they're not on the question page either - but I cannot remember whether they were previously.
[image]

*Edit:* This morning, 16 Dec 08:30 GMT, they seem to be fixed…

[image]

Comment: Same here, with Firefox

Comment: Wasn't this always the case? I figured it had to do with how that specific instance of the avatar was rendered..

Comment: @Joachim - it's an overlay, should be the same for all instances. It always rendered in previous years. [I know nothing about html/css, just what it's always looked like in the past.]

Comment: I can't even get it to show on the profile-page. Winter-bash page doesn't show the hat, but the list of hats shows one is selected. Brave 64 on windows 10, up to date.

Comment: It also doesn't show on the question list, only on the user cards on the actual questions and answers.

Comment: Hats do show in chat, both next to the text entry box and with the smaller avatars in the chat history, so it's not an issue with the size of the avatar.

Comment: This appears to be fixed now.

Comment: Not here it's not @TimothyG. The hat is *behind* my profile picture, not on top of it. (Sprite, anyone?)

Comment: @W.O. for me it is on Chrome desktop and mobile https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7dH5.png  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XbDd.png  Maybe do a hard refresh?

Comment: The hats come out just fine in Chrome -  just brave being awkward. Thanks for the tip. @TimothyG.

Comment: For me (in Firefox) it's working now, as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone thinking they're being gaslit, this was in fact a problem at the start of Winter Bash. Our top bar has gone through several iterations over the months and has had a series of CSS class changes. Winter Bash was looking for old classes and therefore couldn't find the avatar with the new classes.

This was fixed yesterday (2022-12-15) so fear not if you're questioning your sanity about this not being a problem anymore.

Comment: Thank you for confirming a) I wasn't going slightly mad & b) the tech details behind it :))

Comment: \*Ahem\*, what allejo *means* to say is... "What bug? No idea what you're talking about."